# Returning static variable throws error in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, c++14

Returning or accessing a static variable inside a static function throws an error in Visual Studio:

```cpp
// H File
class LayoutManager : public QObject
{
    static int Access_Data();
    static int data;
};
```

```cpp
// CPP

static int data= 0; // Global scope

int LayoutManager::Access_Data()
{
    data= data+ 1;
    return data;
}
```

```
Error: Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static int LayoutManager::data" (?mm@LayoutManager@@2HA)
```

After changing to `int LayoutManager::data = 0` in C++, the error is gone, but while assigning a new value to `data` in another class, it throws a new error:

```cpp
void MyLayout::Update( void )
{
    LayoutManager::data = 1;  // error here
```

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question, if the answer didn't solve your problem add a comment to the answer. If you have a new question raise a new question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int LayoutManager::data = 0;
```

This tells the compiler that you mean the `data` variable in the `LayoutManager` class and not a regular global variable outside of any class.

It's also an error to repeat the `static` keyword. The compiler already knows the variable is static from the declaration.